# How to select by child collection value in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am just stuck.. trying to select records from a table (LINQ to EF) based on a value in a child collection.

I have a Tour Entity that has relationship (many - many collection) to Category table.
I need to select Tours by category..

Here is my query:

```
var _tours = from _tr in Context.Tours.Where(i => i.IsActive == true)
                     .Include(cat => cat.TourCategories)//.Where(id => d.TourCategoryID == tourCategory)
                     select _tr;
        return _tours;
```

the query works but not when I try to filter by category id.. (tourCategory is int Id)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var _tours = Context.Tours.Where(i => i.IsActive == true)
  .Include(cat => cat.TourCategories).
  .Where(x => x.TourCategories.Any(y => y.TourCategoryID == tourCategory)
```